# Change permissions of file in CMake

Tags: bash, shell, build, permissions, cmake

I created a shell script using CMake just like this:
`file(WRITE somescript.sh "echo foo!")`

I want the user to be able to execute that script right away. For this, it would be nice to change the permissions of that file from within CMake.

Is there something like `chmod u+x somescript.sh` in CMake?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with `install` is that existing files are not overwritten when the destination directory is equal to the source directory and when the files themselves did not change (CMake seems to compare timestamps). But nevermind, I found a working solution for everyone reading along:

1. Create the file as shown in the question but in a temporary folder `${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/tmp`
2. Use `file (COPY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/tmp/somescript.sh DESTINATION ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR} FILE_PERMISSIONS OWNER_EXECUTE OWNER_WRITE OWNER_READ)`
3. Remove the old file and the temporary directory: `file(REMOVE_RECURSIVE ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/tmp/)`

Comment: REMOVE_RECURSIVE doesn't work for me. It is *REMOVE_RECURSE*, as mentioned in the official documentation https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.10/command/file.html

Answer (score 1):

You can do that in the istall command. Use this tags:

```
install(
    FILES somescript.sh
    PERMISSIONS OWNER_EXECUTE OWNER_WRITE OWNER_READ
    DESTINATION /some/destination
)
```

Comment: Tried this on a  linux pc and indeed it worked , but on windows though.. I think its not cross-compatible solution

Comment: So verbose. You don't happen to know if there is a more compact way to set permissions?

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to copy a binary I would use USE_SOURCE_PERMISSIONS

Answer (score 0):

Since cmake version 3.19, it's now possible to use the file(CHMOD ...) command. The syntax is:

```
file(CHMOD <files>... <directories>... [PERMISSIONS <permissions>...] [FILE_PERMISSIONS <permissions>...] [DIRECTORY_PERMISSIONS <permissions>...])
```

For example:

```
file(CHMOD somescript.sh PERMISSIONS OWNER_EXECUTE OWNER_WRITE OWNER_READ)
```

See the [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/file.html#chmod) for more details.